# Get the distinct count of one column based on 3 different labels present in another column using pandas

Tags: pandas

Input:

| Type | count |
| --- | --- |
| manager | 123 |
| manager | 123 |
| manager | 111 |
| manager | 222 |
| tech lead | 888 |
| tech lead | 888 |
| tech lead | 888 |
| tech lead | 444 |
| developer | 234 |
| developer | 567 |
| developer | 890 |

Output: want the distinct count of each label i.e manager,techlead, developer

| Type | count |
| --- | --- |
| manager | 3 |
| tech lead | 2 |
| developer | 3 |

Comment: `.groupby('Type').count()` ?

Comment: @Psidom. Missing `.drop_duplicates(...)`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Like to start, do you know [how to use groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)? For tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). This might also be useful: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html)*:

```
df.groupby('Type', as_index=False, sort=False)['count'].nunique()
```

```
        Type  count
0    manager      3
1  tech lead      2
2  developer      3
```

---

* *link is currently dead; for now use the docs for [1.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) or [dev](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html)*

Answer (score 0):

To get expected output, you have to drop some duplicates values:

```
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['Type', 'count'])
       .value_counts('Type')
       .rename('count').reset_index())

        Type  count
0  developer      3
1    manager      3
2  tech lead      2

>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['Type', 'count'])
       .groupby('Type', as_index=False)['count']
       .count())  # or .nunique(), or .size()

        Type  count
0  developer      3
1    manager      3
2  tech lead      2
```